# Spring-data-rest-webmvc: Why cannot the ObjectError be rendered directly when handling the exception - MethodArgumentNotValidException?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-validator, exceptionhandler

In light of the [`DefaultErrorAttributes`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.java), where `ObjectError` can be used to express the error details, I intended to utilize `ObjectError` to express the error details when handling the exception - MethodArgumentNotValidException` in the implementation of a *REST* API with pure *Spring 5*.

I handled `MethodArgumentNotValidException` by `extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {       request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_STATUS_CODE_ATTRIBUTE, status.value(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE, ex, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    BindingResult re = ((MethodArgumentNotValidException) ex).getBindingResult();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(re.getAllErrors().get(0), headers, status);
  }
}
```

In the code above, the `BindingResult` instance eventually called `getAllErrors()` to `return` a `List` of `ObjectError`s. I just tried to get the first element from the `List` of `ObjectError`s, and then presumably would render the `ObjectError` in *JSON* format for testing purpose. However, **when running it with *Jetty*, even though the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is handled in the mentioned exception handler - `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` (this is proved with debugger), the JSON for `ObjectError` could not be rendered in JSON format, instead the default html error page of the Jetty web container is displayed**

The error html code generated from Jetty is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /masterdata/cities. Reason:

        <pre>    Bad Request</pre>
    </p>
    <h3>Caused by:</h3>
    <pre>org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.rx.entity.City com.rx.rest.controller.CityController.createCity(com.rx.entity.City): [Field error in object &apos;city&apos; on field &apos;city&apos;: rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.city.city,NotNull.city,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [city.city,city]; arguments []; default message [city]]; default message [city cannot be empty]] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:859)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>
<hr>
            <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.14.v20181114</a>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quetion: **Why cannot the `ObjectError` be rendered directly when handling the exception - `MethodArgumentNotValidException`?**

Comment: provide jetty logs + html page you got

Comment: The html code of error page is copied there now. But the Jetty logs does not contain any useful information with the default log configuration